# Usage of post_formats

Tags: post-formats

During the process of developing my first serious theme I stumbled over a basical question: how should I use the post_formats?

I know what post_formats are useful for. But for learning purpose I downloaded several more or less professional themes and tried to get into the source code. And I found out that different author use them differently.

The first possibility is to use them for reducing your code in your `index.php` like in the [Baskerville theme](https://wordpress.org/themes/baskerville). This theme names its files containing the formats `content-*.php`. In those files the author specified the short versions of your posts using `<?php the_excerpt('100'); ?>`. I like this idea because your overview over your blog is mostly the first site a user sees and in the first seconds he or she decides about closing the tab or continuing reading. The blog page of the mentioned theme is indeed very inviting.

On the other hand you use posts_formats to reduce the code in `single.php` like the author of the [Bones theme](https://github.com/eddiemachado/bones/blob/master/single.php). But therefore they use some generic to display the blog overview defined in `index.php`.

Are there any arguments for one of the two methods? Is there a third way on how to handle this (like defining formats for `index.php` and `single.php` seperatly)?

Comment: There really is no single answer for this. If you are making a general purpose blog theme, then using your first example of `content-*.php` is probably going to serve you better. But as you move away from that towards custom themes or themes meant for purpose beside general blogging, then you have to pick what works best for you.

Comment: Maybe a third way could be suitable too for larger themes. You could create a folder `blog` with post formats for your blog page and a `single` folder containing all formats for your single posts. This would be very obvious and avoid bloated files in the root of your folder (of course using some general functions defined in `functions.php` like `post_meta()`)